Is mevushal wine which had non-mevushal wine added to it kosher if handled by gentiles
According to Halacha, if non-pasteurized/non-mevushal wine is added to mevushal wine, is it non-kosher if handled by gentiles? Or no, is it relied  on Rov that it is kosher if it is majority pasteurized wine? If not Rov, is 1/60 bittul relied on?

I don't know the answer, but since the whole principle of mevushal is that it wouldn't be fit for idolatrous libation, perhaps there's also no need to worry that an idol worshipper would use a mixture?

I would imagine we treat the mevushal wine like any other liquid, in which case the halacha is the same as if someone put some non-kosher wine in any liquid, i.e. it needs to be less than 1/6th or 1/60th depending on the opinion

According to this answer, it would be permitted if there's less than a sixth non-mevushal wine, because wine diluted to less than a sixth is not considered wine at all.
But there's a responsum of the Tashbatz in which he discusses the question and concludes it's best to avoid it at any ratio, because we don't know what the threshold was to disqualify wine from the idol worshipers' service:

ולפי שאין אנו בקיאין בדרכי עבודתן ואפשר שלא היו נמנעין מלנסך אא"כ היה
כלו מבושל על כן ראוי למחו' בדבר ואל ינהגו קלות ראש במה שלא נהגו היתר
עד עתה

